# Free Directshow filter for face detection from webcam samples

Tags: visual-c++, filter, directshow, face-detection

Is there any directshow filter available that has face detection feature(detects the face from live webcam source) ? Please guide.

Thanks,
Shyam

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create one using the Open-CV library. It has a good face detection algorithm.